# Recharts How To Show Data Grouped

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts

I'm working with Recharts, I'm trying to do a simple "Line chart" for the payments transactions across the whole year.

So here's what I made so far

```
export const BankTransactionsChart: React.FC<Props> = ({ chartHeight = 400 }) => {
    const data = [
        { key: 'Jan', date: '1-Jan-2019', amount: '12' },
        { key: 'Feb', date: '1-Feb-2019', amount: '56' },
        { key: 'Feb', date: '5-Feb-2019', amount: '76' },
        { key: 'Mar', date: '1-Mar-2019', amount: '-112' },
        { key: 'Apr', date: '1-Apr-2019', amount: '-40' },
        { key: 'May', date: '1-May-2019', amount: '30' },
        { key: 'Jun', date: '1-Jun-2019', amount: '50' },
        { key: 'Jul', date: '1-Jul-2019', amount: '60' },
        { key: 'Aug', date: '1-Aug-2019', amount: '70' },
        { key: 'Sep', date: '1-Sep-2019', amount: '50' },
        { key: 'Oct', date: '1-Oct-2019', amount: '20' },
        { key: 'Nov', date: '1-Nov-2019', amount: '10' },
        { key: 'Dec', date: '1-Dec-2019', amount: '0' }
    ];

    const customizeTick = (props: any) => {
        const { x, y, payload } = props;
        return (
            <text x={x - 10} y={y + 15} textAnchor="start" fill="#666">
                {payload.value}
            </text>
        );
    };
    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer className="bank-transactions-chart-container" width="95%" height={chartHeight}>
            <LineChart className="bank-transactions-chart" data={data} margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
                <XAxis dataKey="date" allowDataOverflow tick={(props: any) => customizeTick(props)} />
                <YAxis />
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36} />
                <Line type="monotone" dataKey="amount" stroke="#82ca9d" name="Amount" />
            </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
};
```

This outputs the image below,
[image: Graph output]

if you can see in the data array in the code I have two transactions for February, but in the graph above in the x axis its showing only the label for 5-Feb-2019.

I'm trying to put 12 months regardless the dates in the data array and render the dots accordingly to their corresponding months.

Is it in the tick function?

Please help me out,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fundamentally odd question. a line is line because it has ONLY ONE y-point (value) for every given x-point (value).

I assume it may be solve this issue if you plot 2 lines overlapping each other where there's only one (the same) value is available and would show a "fork" where it has two different values.

change the data like:

```
const data = [
        { key: 'Jan', date: '1-Jan-2019', amount1: '12' amount2: '12' },
        { key: 'Feb', date: '1-Feb-2019', amount1: '56' amount2: '76' },
        { key: 'Mar', date: '1-Mar-2019', amount1: '-112' amount2: '-112' },
        ...
    ];
```

and plot two line series:

```
      ...
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36} />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="amount1" stroke="#82ca9d" name="Amount" />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="amount2" stroke="#82ca9d" name="Amount" />
    </LineChart>
...
```